# XPath with recursive definitions

Tags: xml, xpath, dtd

I have a DTD like this :

```
     <!ELEMENT Root (Thread*) >
     <!ELEMENT Thread(ThreadId, Message) >
    <!ELEMENT Replies(message+) >
     <!ELEMENT message(timestamp, sender, recipient, subject, text, Replies?)>
```

So a thread will have a message and this message can have a node 'replies', then this node can contain messages and so on until the bottom of the structure.

Now what I want to do is to first retrieve the ID of the thread with the most messages and then retrieve the ID of the thread with the longest chain of nested replies.

It feels like a recursive problem but I'm not able to approach it in XPath.  So far I tried something like this :

```
      For $thread in //thread
      Count(descendant-or-self::$thread/message)
```

For each thread I Try to count the number of children messages nodes, but this solution counts the number of All the children nodes of the thread, therefore including Replies nodes.

I'm feeling lost with this kind of problems as I cannot figure out what to do in these 'recursive situations'.

Comment: So which version of XPath do you have access to? 2.0, 3.0, 3.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming XPath 3.0 you can use e.g.

```
let $max := max(/Root/Thread/count(.//Message))
return /Root/Thread[count(.//Message) eq $max]/ThreadId
```

to find the id(s) of the thread(s) with most messages and I think

```
let $max := max(/Root/Thread/Message//Replies[not(Message/Replies)]/count(ancestor::Replies))
return /Root/Thread[Message//Replies[not(Message/Replies)]/count(ancestor::Replies) = $max]/ThreadId
```

to find the id(s) of the thread(s) with the longest chain of nested replies.

With XPath 2.0 you don't have `let` expressions so you would have to inline the code bound in my samples to the variable in the place where the variable is referenced.

In XPath 3.1 you have a `sort` function (https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-sort) so instead of computing the maximum and selecting the items with the maximum you could sort and take the last e.g.

```
sort(/Root/Thread, (), function($t) { max($t/Message//Replies[not(Message/Replies)]/count(ancestor::Replies)) })[last()]/ThreadId
```

for the second, more complex query or

```
sort(/Root/Thread, (), function($t) { count($t//Message) })[last()]/ThreadId
```

for the first one.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers , I'm using XPath 3.0! They do work!

Comment: Hello again, I need one last thing! To find the thread with the longest chain of nested replies would it work to simply find the max of the count of the Replies in a thread, like this :     `count(/Root/Thread//Replies)`                                                    
 In this way we also count the first reply but I guess it doesn't matter as we'll have the number of nested replies plus the first reply, for each thread.

Comment: The problem is that the expression `count(/Root/Thread//Replies)` counts all `Replies` descendants both in the depth as well as the breadth of the tree so I wouldn't see that as a way to determine the maximum nesting.